# Relation between $R^2$ and $R^2_{(i)}$

Tags: regression, outliers, residuals

Is there a relation between $R^2$ and $R^2_{(i)}$ (where $R^2_{(i)}$ is the $R^2$ of a regression without the point ith. For example if the ith point is an outlier) without having to recalculate all the regression without the ith point?. I need some kind of relation similar to the relation that exists between the stundetized residuals and the standarized residuals.

Comment: You can easily construct that using [Cook's distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook%27s_distance)

Comment: Please, could you be more expecific?. For exemple I know that the relation between $t_i$ and $r_i$ is $t_i=r_i( \frac{n-p-1}{n-p-r^2_i} )^{\frac{1}{2}}$ where $t_i$ is the ith-stundetized residual, $r_i$ is the ith-standarized residual, n are the number of points and p the number of variables. How can I relate $R^2$ and $R^2_{(i)}$ with the Cook's Distance?

Comment: you could use the fact that $R^2=1-\pmb e'\pmb e/\pmb v'\pmb v$ where $\pmb e$ is the vector of regression residuals and $\pmb v$ is the vector of regression residuals when the only independent variable is the constant term. Using Cook's algorithm you can obtain the leave i-th out version of $\pmb e$ and $\pmb v$ and just plug them in the formula.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer by myself. It is an "ugly" formula but it works.
This is the relationship between $R^2(i)$ and $R^2$:

$R^{2}(i)=1-(1-R^{2})\left(1-\frac{r_{i}^{2}}{n-k-1}\right)\frac{(n-1)SS}{(n-1)SS-n(\bar{y}-y_{i})^{2}}$

Where:

- $R^2(i)$ is the $R^2$ os a regression where the ih observeations has been removed.
- $R^2$ is the $R^2$ of a regression with all the observations
- $r_i$ is the error $e_i$ standarized $r_i=\frac{e_i}{\hat{\sigma}_R\sqrt{1-h_{ii}}}$
- n is the number of observation
- k is the number of variables (with out the intercept. For example is we have only one variable $x_1$ k=1)
- SS are the sum of squares $SS=\sum{(y-\bar{y})^2}$
- $\bar{y}$ is the mean(y)
- $y_i$ is the deleted observation